# Perl script called from Perl doesn't seem to flush stdout

Tags: perl, stdout

I have two Perl scripts — let's call them `script.pl` and `script2.pl`.

`script2.pl` updates to the command line, as in:

```
print "Progress $progress percent...\r";
```

In order to get this to work I had to turn on autoflush at the start of `script2.pl`:

```
$|++;
```

Now, the problem arises because I have to have `script2.pl` called from `script.pl`, and this — the updating/flushing — only seems to work when `script2.pl` is run directly, not when it's called from `script.pl`.

I've tried various ways of calling `script2.pl`, from `system()` to backticks and in no case does the updating happen.

Am I missing something about handling stdout output when one Perl script is called from another?

Comment: How do you call `script2.pl` from within `script.pl`?

Comment: Currently I'm just using `\`script2.pl\`` in backticks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling with backticks will spawn a new `perl` process, and for that process, the auto-flushing will be set. That means that whatever output comes out of `script2.pl` will come out as soon as it gets printed. Of course doing

```
my $output = `perl script2.pl`;
```

will mean you are not actually reading it while it's being output, but rather you're asking for all the output to end up in `$output` when it's done.

The `$|` in the `perl` process that runs `script2.pl` has **no influence** on `script.pl`. If you want your `script.pl` process to have unbuffered output, turn off buffering there.

---

An alternative might be to not run `script2.pl` as a separate process, but rather to refactor it to be a module and call it properly, or use `do` or `require` to call it once. In either case the change to `$|` would then happen within the same Perl interpreter, and thus would have an effect.

Of course it's not a good idea if an internal part of your application messes with your application's output buffering. The best way would be to refactor this to be a module without changing the buffering in that module, and in your program where you use it, set the buffering to what you need it to be *for that specific program*. Always let the consumer decide what they want, even if that's only yourself.

Comment: It might be that I misunderstood your question. In that case, please clarify.

Comment: No, I think you got me. I appreciate the clarification. I thought since I'd turned off buffering in both with `$|++` and since they were being executed in the same console, I'd see it — but I guess it makes sense that they're not technically the same stdout. Thanks for this answer.

Comment: @KT_ if you've got it turned on in both scripts it should be working. However if you shell out from `script.pl` to `script2.pl` it really doesn't matter whether `script2.pl` has `$|++` or not.

Comment: @KT_: Running a program using backticks stores the output ***instead*** of printing it to the screen. You can print the result after the run finishes, but you will get the whole thing at once.